# Create a pyspark kernel and interact via another python process

Tags: python, pyspark, python-interactive

Dear fellow members of community.
I have spark 3.4.0 installed and set up. To run a pyspark terminal, I set up environment variables and it works fine.
I have a python microservice which receives a python code to run on pyspark terminal. How can I initialize a pyspark terminal inside my running python microservice and interact with it?

Even if we exclude spark out of the picture, how can I initialize a python kernel
I read about jupyter kernels but unable to get the picture on how to create one?

Tried following the post:
https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/kernels.html